# Gentoo / Emerging the latest version of qtwebengine fails

Tags: linux, command-line, compile, gentoo, c

Command: `emerge qtwebengine`

```
COMMON_FLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
MAKEOPTS="-j3"
USE="-bindist"
```

RAM: 4 Gb

I have tried removing -pipe, and setting -j1, and also adding -jumbo-build to USE flags,
but not the both at the same time. `dmesg | grep oom` returns nothing

```
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
```

`some random gibberish`

```
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make[3]: *** [Makefile.gn_run:510: run_ninja] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3/work/qtwebengine-everywhere-src-5.11.3/src/core'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:80: sub-gn_run-pro-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3/work/qtwebengine-everywhere-src-5.11.3/src/core'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:79: sub-core-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3/work/qtwebengine-everywhere-src-5.11.3/src'
make: *** [Makefile:47: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
 [31;01m*[0m ERROR: dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 [31;01m*[0m   emake failed
 [31;01m*[0m 
 [31;01m*[0m If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3::gentoo'`,
 [31;01m*[0m the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3::gentoo'`.
 [31;01m*[0m The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3/temp/build.log'.
 [31;01m*[0m The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3/temp/environment'.
 [31;01m*[0m Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3/work/qtwebengine-everywhere-src-5.11.3'
 [31;01m*[0m S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.11.3/work/qtwebengine-everywhere-src-5.11.3'
```

Comment: I've been getting this myself over past few versions and keep skipping it because I can't figure it out. I removed it from tmpfs, decreased to -t3 on a quad core, jumbo-build isn't set. Right before "build stopped" it has "obj/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/platform/multi_channel_resampler.o". Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

/var/tmp/portage is a tmpfs, right? Jest unmount it before the compilation, and the working data will be stored on the disk.